# How to make status bar reappear after dismissing uiimagepickerviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am hiding the status bar in my application when I present my uiimagepickerviewcontroller modally.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

In the callback method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

I execute the following methods:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
```

before calling:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {}];
```

I've tried "showing" the status bar in the completion block to no avail. How should I go about in getting the status bar to reappear after dismissing my uiimagepickerviewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it back in the view controllers dismissal completion handler:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(BOOL done){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
}];
```

Although this is strange, there isn't any reason as to why this wouldn't be working jumping out at me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in iOS 11. I could make the statusBar re-appear in the following way:

In `Info.plist`, set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES`:

[image]

In the view controller that presents the `UIImagePickerController`, implement

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```